# rails before_filter preventing access to controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, before-filter

I've got an app where the user can nominate a keyholder who can also view their account. I've got a before_filter than means that only the account holder, or their keyholder, can view their account. This code works fine for either person viewing the user's home page, but I can't do anything further - I am currently logged in as the keyholder, and I can't log out, or add 'notes' to either account (right now the keyholder has unrestricted access to their own account and the person they are keyholder for). Please can anyone help?

The before_filter is:

```
def correct_user
        @user = User.find(params[:id])

        unless (@user && current_user.id == @user.id) || ((current_user.access_id==@user.id)&&(current_user.id==@user.access_id))
          redirect_to root_path
        end
      end
```

and the error I am getting when trying to e.g. create a note is:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in NotesController#new 
Couldn't find User without an ID
```

it is referring to the @user line in the before_filter.

How come when I am logged in as the keyholder, I can view the homepage, but do nothing else? Thanks!

UPDATE:

Updated before_filter (in application_controller.rb):

```
def correct_user
        if params[:id]
          @user = User.find(params[:id])

          unless (@user && current_user.id == @user.id) || ((current_user.access_id==@user.id)&&(current_user.id==@user.access_id))
            redirect_to root_path
          end
        else
          redirect_to root_path
        end
      end
```

Console output on note creation:

```
Started POST "/notes" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-28 14:10:49 +0000
Processing by NotesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"V", "authenticity_token"=>"qMDHQAoC4l3Be5YZKSH1AJ9E5zS1D
kMNCW2KzUZ38gM=", "note"=>{"user_id"=>"16", "content"=>""}, "commit"=>"Update Note"}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :correct_user rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 98ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-28 14:10:49 +0000
Processing by PublicController#index as HTML
  ←[1m←[36mUser Load (3.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users
"."id" = 16 LIMIT 1←[0m
  Rendered public/index.html.erb within layouts/application (5.0ms)
  ←[1m←[36mTimeline Load (3.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "timelines".* FROM "timelines"
WHERE "timelines"."user_id" = 16 LIMIT 1←[0m
  ←[1m←[36mMessageBoard Load (2.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "message_boards".* FROM "me
ssage_boards" WHERE "message_boards"."user_id" = 16 LIMIT 1←[0m
  Rendered partials/_menuoptions.html.erb (53.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 551ms (Views: 535.0ms | ActiveRecord: 16.0ms)
```

Comment: when you go the the notes controller, you don't have a `params[:id]` which is what's causing the error.

Comment: Why is that error being caused, and why is it also preventing me from logging out? The id isn't even getting passed to the devise destroy session action?

Comment: you can't log out because the before filter takes precedence before destroying the session

Comment: but how come it isn't getting passed the @user parameter, when it worked fine before I added the before filter?

Comment: @user is not persisted in between requests. once a new request is started, all instance variables in the previous request is gone.

Comment: Is is not held within the session? I'm using devise for authentication, so doesn't it destroy the session of 'current_user' - in which case why is that being affected along with the rest of the controllers? I don't know why the before_filter is affecting the ability of the keyholder to set up their own notes etc. as well as everything else?

Comment: the before_filter is places in application controller so it is called on **every** action.  only current_user is taken from the session and is provided by devise.

Comment: But how come the before filter isn't working then - as it should in theory only prevent someone who isn't the user or their keyholder from performing any action?

Comment: See this line in your output: `Filter chain halted as :correct_user rendered or redirected`. This is what `before_filter` is doing. And you are not able to do anything. There is no user with the `params[:id]` in the `correct_user` action. And your filter chain halted.

Comment: it isn't working because it expects you to have a `params[:id]` on every request.

Comment: @jvnill - you are right and that is what I wrote above.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Is it possible to alter the before_filter so that it doesn't require the id parameter in all requests?

Comment: before_filter doesn't require the id. Your correct_user method requires the id params.

Comment: Sorry - I meant the correct_user method - it is a before_filter called in the application controller. All I want is a before filter that will check that the user is either the account owner or the keyholder before performing any action - any suggestions/alterations to mine?

Comment: Ok I posted the answer.Check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
def correct_user
            if current_user
              @user = User.find(current_user.id)

              unless (@user && current_user.id == @user.id) || ((current_user.access_id==@user.id)&&(current_user.id==@user.access_id))
                redirect_to root_path
              end
            else
              redirect_to root_path
            end
          end
```

Actually, there is no `params[:id]` like thing here. The `current_user` is the user whom you are checking so you can directly find with `current_user.id` as above. Replace the code with above and rectify for possible best if you find other. It is just an idea for implementation.

Comment: I still have a doubt that account owner or the keyholder is the person whose id you are passing in this `correct_user` action. Just find out that why you are not getting the id of that person. You can't put this `before_filter` directly in application controller because it will directly pass the nil params for such person. In the beginning you don't have any such person to check for. You must provide the person id params somewhere that should be passed to `correct_user` action.

Comment: My mistake - i had a rogue snippet of code in my controller that I had used to attempt to pass the id in the action. Removed that, and the filter works fine, thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're validating too much on a single action, anyway the problem seems to be in the get/post request, since there is no id getting to the controller action, can you attach the params being sent to the controller? copy them from the console, it will be easier to read...

```
 "note"=>{"user_id"=>"16", "content"=>""}
```

You've to use `params[:note][:user_id]` to get the user id, you'll have to add a hidden field with the user id for being able to do what you want, if you ask me, I don't see it as a good practice, have you seen any railscast?, I'm pretty sure that you can find a lot of helpful tips on there, look at this one for example:

[Railscast Cancan](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan)

Hope it helps...

Comment: I've added it to the original question now

Comment: Yes, I've seen the one on CanCan, and looked through the documentation before trying to do it myself - it doesn't seem built to allow just one single user access to another nominated account, just different levels of user i.e. admins, users etc, who would have the same permissions across all accounts?

Comment: With cancan you can define all the permissions that you want, it's a bit tricky in some cases, but the easy path here I believe that is a hidden field on the form holding the user id..

Answer (score 0):

When you go yo notes/new, you are not providing any id param, and that is the reason for you to get this exception.

You have to check first if params[:id] exists:

```
def correct_user
  if params[:id]
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    unless (@user && current_user.id == @user.id) || ((current_user.access_id==@user.id)&&(current_user.id==@user.access_id))
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  else
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

and in the link to notes/new you have to provide the id param for the user:

```
<%= link_to "New note on #{@user.name}", new_note_path(id: @user.id) %>
```

Comment: Just curious regarding `link_to` above: Why to need params id in new action? The form of `new.html.erb` will auto create the id on submition because this is the primary key auto increment field.

Comment: But the ID in this case is not to look up in the notes model, it is for the users model

Comment: Even if the id is not to look up if we do something like: `Notes.create(:field1 => "value1", :field2 => "value2")` without giving the id value then also it will create the row with auto id incremented. Also the create action requires the id but not the new action because it is where we are sending id params.

Comment: Thanks for that - if I add that to the link_to, I can get to the form for creating a new note, but when I try and press submit at the bottom of the form, it gives me an error: Couldn't find User without an ID, even though the request parameters include the User ID?  "note"=>{"user_id"=>"16",

Comment: this is what I am saying that this `user id 16 row` is not yet saved at the time you are submitting to database. So you are getting this error. The way is don't pass params to new but pass them to create action.

Comment: But I am just trying to create a new note where the user_id would be 16 - which is passed to the form as a hidden field, so why is that not working? And why is the log out also not working?

Comment: Are you sure that hidden field params are passed to the controllers' create action? I don't think so and that is the cause of your error. Please provide the console params output that you are getting on form submition.

Comment: I've added the relevant output to the original question now.